# Bypass node access with Panels

Tags: 7, views, theming, panels, users

I'm using modules [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) and [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).

I need to modify the appearance of a node according to its accessibility by the user.

With Panels, I made 2 variants with selection rules (page "Node template"):

1. when the node is not accessible
2. when it is accessible.

But when the user has no access to the node he has a denied access and not the panel.

Do you know how to bypass node access with [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels)?

Comment: Do you actually want to show the user some of the content of the node, or just give them a custom page (eg. to prompt them to sign up)?

Comment: Please explain the main problem..? What you actual want..?

Comment: Which "rules" do you mean, the "Rules" module, or something else? Plese EDIT your question to clarify that.

Comment: @Alfred Armstrong some of the content of the node (for example : the title, the teaser and the comments)

Comment: @Kamal Oberoi To summarize: I wish to show a teaser of an article when the user has no access to the content, and all the article when there is access. I thought of using Panels, but it has can be another solution there.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens the selection rules in variant of the panels module

Comment: The whole intention of Content Access and other such modules is to ensure the user cannot access the node, so you'll be forced to work round it pretty drastically, and there's a risk of opening a security hole. Consider using field permissions instead, with some custom templating.

Comment: @Alfred Armstrong thanks for warning me, the consideration on the security is very important. I looked at field permissions, but it seems to me that he allows only to restrict the access by user's role (and not by node), have I well? Indeed, I need a granularity by node (the user buys this article (via drupal commerce), he can read all this article but not the others).

Comment: you can add permission Artical content type to anonymous

Answer (score 0):

To overrider the default `Access Denied` page of the Drupal, you have to change the path of this page.

To change the page path, follow these steps:

1. Go to `admin/config/system/site-information`.
2. At the bottom of the page, there is a `Error Pages` section.
3. There is a field `Default 403 (access denied) page`. Provide your custom panel page link.
4. And the save it.

I hope it will work.

Comment: thanks for this proposal. It is not going to raise problem for example when the denied access will not be in touch with the access in a node?